# how to show iads banner view on both simulator and iphone or ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi friend i makeing iads application but it is not showing on simulator and iphone.

help me where i am wrong in code.

Give me some details of how `iAds` work.

this is my code

```
frontpage.h file

UIView* contentView;
    id adBannerView;
    BOOL adBannerViewIsVisible;
    UITableView *_tableView;


//IAdBanner property
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id adBannerView;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL adBannerViewIsVisible;





frontpage.m file



- (int)getBannerHeight:(UIDeviceOrientation)orientation {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        return 32;
    } else {
        return 50;
    }
}

- (int)getBannerHeight {
    return [self getBannerHeight:[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark create BannerView:
- (void)createAdBannerView {
    Class classAdBannerView = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");
    if (classAdBannerView != nil) {
        self.adBannerView = [[[classAdBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        [adBannerView setRequiredContentSizeIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil]];
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {
            [adBannerView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape];
        } else {
            [adBannerView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];            
        }
        [adBannerView setFrame:CGRectOffset([adBannerView frame], 0, -[self getBannerHeight])];
        [adBannerView setDelegate:self];

        [self.view addSubview:adBannerView];        
    }
}

- (void)fixupAdView:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    if (adBannerView != nil) {        
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
            [adBannerView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape];
        } else {
            [adBannerView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
        }          
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"fixupViews" context:nil];
        if (adBannerViewIsVisible) {
            CGRect adBannerViewFrame = [adBannerView frame];
            adBannerViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
            adBannerViewFrame.origin.y = 0;
            [adBannerView setFrame:adBannerViewFrame];
            CGRect contentViewFrame = contentView.frame;
            contentViewFrame.origin.y = [self getBannerHeight:toInterfaceOrientation];
            contentViewFrame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height - [self getBannerHeight:toInterfaceOrientation];
            contentView.frame = contentViewFrame;
        } else {
            CGRect adBannerViewFrame = [adBannerView frame];
            adBannerViewFrame.origin.x = 0;
            adBannerViewFrame.origin.y = -[self getBannerHeight:toInterfaceOrientation];
            [adBannerView setFrame:adBannerViewFrame];
            CGRect contentViewFrame = contentView.frame;
            contentViewFrame.origin.y = 0;
            contentViewFrame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height;
            contentView.frame = contentViewFrame;            
        }
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }   
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark ADBannerViewDelegate

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    if (!adBannerViewIsVisible) {                
        adBannerViewIsVisible = YES;
        [self fixupAdView:[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (adBannerViewIsVisible)
    {        
        adBannerViewIsVisible = NO;
        [self fixupAdView:[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];
    }
    //NSLog(@"bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@",[error localizedDescription]);

}
```

Comment: Is your app crashing on iphone

Comment: @gypsa no my app not crashing why is not loading